# How to access a viewcontroller property from the main app delegate?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, controller, refresh, xcode4.5

My project is a window with a tabbarcontroller and 3 viewcontrollers. The first viewcontroller has a datepicker. I'm using the current day (`[NSDate date]`) as the maximum limit of the picker.

The problem is that I'm not being able to refresh that picker with the newer date (supposing I'm running the app some days after, for example).

After researching this forum I figured out that I'd have to do the refresh in this method (in the delegate file): `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`

But I couldn't create a correct reference to the first view controller from there.
I tried to use a pointer to `[self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]` but it seems that it doesn't point to the view controller.

Does someone have any thoughts about this problem?

Here is the code:

```
//
//  PNAppDelegate.m
//

#import "PNAppDelegate.h"
#import "PPPViewController.h"
#import "IGPreviaViewController.h"
#import "IGUsgViewController.h"


@implementation PNAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    PPPViewController *pppvc = [[PPPViewController alloc] init];


    IGPreviaViewController *igpvc = [[IGPreviaViewController alloc] init];


    IGUsgViewController *iguvc = [[IGUsgViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pppvc, igpvc, iguvc, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{





    PPPViewController *pppvc = [self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    [pppvc.dumPicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];


   // Here I don't know how to proceed in order to refresh the picker in the first viewcontroller




}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end



//
//  PPPViewController.m
//


#import "PPPViewController.h"
#import "IdadeGestacional.h"


@implementation PPPViewController

@synthesize dumPicker,idadeGest,dataParto,periodoParto,dum;

-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        UITabBarItem *tbi = [self tabBarItem];
        [tbi setTitle:@"IG/DPP"];

        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendario.png"];

        // Put that image on the tab bar item
        [tbi setImage:i];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // cria o dumPicker

    dum = [self acertaData:[NSDate date]];

    dumPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 0, 0)];
    [dumPicker setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)];
    [dumPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [dumPicker setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"]];

    [dumPicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDate *minDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:(-300*24*60*60) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
    [dumPicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
    [dumPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDum) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.view addSubview:dumPicker];




    [idadeGest setText:@""];
    [dataParto setText:@""];
    [periodoParto setText:@""];

}


-(void)changeDum
{    

   // Define a DUM (data inicial)
    NSDate *dataInicial = [[NSDate alloc]init];

    if ([[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] isDaylightSavingTime]) {
        dataInicial = [[dumPicker date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60)];
    }
    else {
        dataInicial = [dumPicker date];
    };


    dum = [self acertaData:dataInicial];





    // Calcula a IG
    IdadeGestacional *IG = [[IdadeGestacional alloc] initWithDataInicial:dum dataFinal:[self acertaData:[NSDate date]]];
    [IG calculaIG];
    [IG display];


    // Mostra a IG
    NSString *IGLabel = @"";
    if (IG.semanas)
    {
        if (IG.dias)
            IGLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ds%dd",IG.semanas,IG.dias];
        else IGLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ds",IG.semanas];
    } else if (IG.dias) IGLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dd",IG.dias];


    [idadeGest setText:IGLabel];

    // Calcula a DPP
    NSDate *dpp = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:(280*24*60*60) sinceDate:dataInicial];

    // Mostra a DPP
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    [dataParto setText:[df stringFromDate:dpp]];

    // Calcula o PPP
    NSDate *pppi = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:(266*24*60*60) sinceDate:dataInicial];
    NSDate *pppf = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:(294*24*60*60) sinceDate:dataInicial];

    // Mostra o PPP
    NSString *PPParto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ a %@",[df stringFromDate:pppi],[df stringFromDate:pppf]];
    [periodoParto setText:PPParto];

}

-(NSDate *)acertaData:(NSDate *)dataBruta
{


    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ;


    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:dataBruta];

    NSDate *novaData = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

    [self mostraData:novaData];

    return novaData;
}

-(void)mostraData:(NSDate *)dataBruta
{
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit | NSCalendarCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:dataBruta];

    NSLog(@"nova data");
    NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d %d %d %@ %@",comps.year,comps.month,comps.day,comps.hour,comps.minute,comps.second,comps.timeZone.abbreviation,comps.calendar.calendarIdentifier);
    NSLog(@"%@",comps.timeZone.name);
}

@end
```

Comment: What language? It would help a lot if you posted your code.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't even mentioned the language in use. It's objective c in Xcode 4.5.2

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to do this in the application delegate and not in the view controller? The `AppDelegate` is in charge of application-wide tasks (hence the delegate methods it employs). If you need to refresh a view inside of a view controller, do it in your view controller -- that's the whole point of the MVC design pattern.

In the case of a `UITabBarController`, I would do this refresh in `viewWillAppear`. In this method, you can update the value of the `maximumDate` property.

**UPDATE:** If `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` don't seem to be getting called upon reactivating the app, you can subscribe to AppDelegate notifications inside of your view controller. Apple's delegation paradigm follows a policy whereby they tend to broadcast notifications that match delegate methods. Case in point: there is a NSNotification called `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. You can subscribe to this notification in `viewWillAppear:` by saying:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) 
                                                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)note {
   self.datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Just be sure to remove this observer in `viewWillDisappear:`

Comment: +1 million. You should absolutely not be accessing a ViewController from the AppDelegate (except for pushing the initial view to the screen but even then you shouldn't keep a reference to that view even.

Comment: Im trying to do this in the app delegate because the view controller methods viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear only works when the application is running and in the foreground. And I want it updated once the user restarts it (when it was in the background).

Comment: Yes, this is true. What's your point? In viewWillAppear, get the value of [NSDate date] and set it as the maximumDate value. Very simple.

Comment: Even better, just say "myDatePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];"...DONE.

Comment: I put an NSLog marker in viewWillAppear and in viewDidAppear. After launch app, click home button and the relaunch it, neither of the two methods got called. Only applicationDidBecomeActive in the delegate.

Comment: What you should possibly doing then is using NSNotificationCenter from the appDelegate to broadcast a "this app just restarted from background" message. The VC will then pick it up and reset its own maximumDate property.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll try to use the notification center and post the results here.

Comment: @Fogmeister makes a good point, but it's overkill for a Notification that already exists. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know you could access that as an NSNotification :D

Answer (score -1):

In your PPPViewController header and implementation file, create a method called 
`- (void)refreshPicker;`

In your implementation of this method, set your dumPicker's maximumDate like this:

```
- (void)refreshPicker
{
    [self.dumPicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Use Notifications. In the applicationDidBecomeActive method, you can call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshPicker" object:nil];
```

and in your viewDidLoad method of PPPViewController, you can add an observer from there by adding this line of code in:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshPicker) object:nil];
```

Comment: That way didnt work. I have to use self.window.rootVienController... But even that doesnt work.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see. I did it in a sample project in Xcode and it worked for me!

Comment: It's bad practise to put anything like this in the AppDelegate. At the very most it should be using NSNotificationCenter to broadcast messages but it shouldn't be accessing VCs directly.

Comment: You can also call `[firstTabBarController.dumPicker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];` at the end of the applicationDidBecomeActive method I put above.

Comment: @Fogmeister also has a very good point. You can use Notifications as well. In the applicationDidBecomeActive method, you can call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshPicker" object:nil];` and in your viewDidLoad method of PPPViewController, you can add an observer from there by adding this line of code in: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshPicker) name:@"refreshPicker" object:nil];`

Comment: Hi Hector. It worked indeed. But as I'll have to refresh data on the other two tabs as well I think that the Notification Center approach would be better. I'll try to use it and post the results. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Plus one me if you can! :)